# Как скрыть текст между <br>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вот такая `html` раскладка элементов

```css
#account_all br {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="account_all" class="main_wrapper">
  <br>
  <b>Warning</b>: Undefined array key "mode" in <b>D:\LocalProjects\ausuppreview-dev\app\public\wp-content\plugins\ultimate-member\includes\core\class-fields.php</b> on line <b>2782</b><br>


  <div id="account"> Some Important Content</div>

</div>
```

Как скрыть отображения всего того что между тегами `<br>` и их тоже ? Желательно через CSS поскольку если отфильтровывать через JS то скорее всего будет эффект исчезания контента на странице. *По техническим причинам отключить этот вывод я не могу.

Comment: Если именно такая семантика html всегда, и доступен только css, я бы использовал хак с `font-size: 0` для всего содержимого, возвращая исходный размер шрифта для контейнера div#account

Answer (score 1):

На css нет идей, как выделить текст, который не находится внутри тегов.

Если на css не получится, можно воспользоваться вот таким скриптом:

```js
const x = document.getElementById('account_all');

let k = 0; // Счетчик BR
const removes = []; // Список элементов на удаление
for (let i of x.childNodes) {
  if (i.nodeName === 'BR') k++; // Увеличиваем счетчик BR
  removes.push(i) // Доабвляем элемент для удаления
  if (k === 2) break; // Останавливаем перебор, если нашли вторую BR
}
removes.forEach(i => i.remove()); // Удаляем элементы по списку
```

```html
<div id="account_all" class="main_wrapper">
  <br>
  <b>Warning</b>: Undefined array key "mode" in <b>D:\LocalProjects\ausuppreview-dev\app\public\wp-content\plugins\ultimate-member\includes\core\class-fields.php</b> on line <b>2782</b>
  <br>

  <div id="account"> Some Important Content</div>

</div>
```

Если его поставить на загрузку страницы, то возможно, исчезновения контента видно не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, за вариант. К сожалению, клипанье этого предупреждения видно, до момента пока скрипт по нему не пройдется.

Comment: А что если `div id="account_all"` скрыть, а после пробегания венуть видимость? Или совсем плохо будет?

Comment: Да, это классная идея. Пользователь не знает сколько грузиться страница, и можно стилями задать display:hidden; потом отфильтровать, а потом снова display:block; вернуть.