# Как удалить теги и все что в них?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой текст `Текст <br><i>Еще что-то</i>` как удалить все теги от сюда и все что внутри эти тегах? Делаю вот так, но удаляет только теги: `text.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')`

Comment: Серьезно? хахах чет огромная она :)

Comment: Оформил комментарий и отправил как ответ. Если хотите правильное решение, то меньше может и получится, но я не знаю как)

Comment: дабавляешь `<style>*{display: none}</style>` и все дела. все что вне тегов должно остаться. для разового случая и так сойдёт.

Comment: Та уже регуляркой сделал

Comment: @user569536 если мой ответ решил вопрос, то, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой (слева от текста ответа, в верхней части)

Comment: Еще вариант, [как удалить теги и текст между ними](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1544246/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-br)

Answer (score -1):

Вот правильное и простое решение:

```regex
<[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*(\s.*?)?>(.*?<\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*>)?
```

### Объяснение

##### Почему `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*`, а не `[a-zA-Z\d]+`?

Имена тегов в HTML могут начинаться только на латинские буквы, а только потом можно использовать цифры, то-есть, `<h1>` — ✅, но `<42>` — ❌. Само выражение можно выразить как-то так: начинается на любую английскую букву и опционально продолжается на любую английскую букву или число.

##### Для чего нужен `(\s.*?)?`?

Это нужно, чтобы убрать атрибуты в элементах, а также символ `/` в одиночных тегах:

`Привет, <input value="мир!" />` -> `Привет,`

##### А это для чего `(.*?<\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*>)?`?

А это убирает текст и второй тег, если элемент имеет два тега, элементы не обязательно имеют два тега, поэтому используется [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (знак `?` после скобки).